# JS get data from django template tag

Tags: javascript, django, authentication, templatetags

I am currently using custom django middleware to check whether the user is authenticated or not. And then use custom templatetag in a template in order to show username/login form

A some point I came across a problem, where I need that authentication info in my js. The only thing I could think of is:

- create hidden element with the auth/not auth flag in it
- get value of that element in js and do whatever I want.

Is there any better way to do such thing?

Comment: You should keep in mind that any JS/HTML code will be viewable and editable by the client.

Comment: you can add the piece of js only for authenticated user with Django templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 copy of JS files, then use template tag to render different one based on the authentication

Then you can keep the authentication decision on the server side.

```
{% if bool %}
    <script src = ....
{% else %}
    <script src = ....
{% endif %}
```

OR:

You can use AJAX in the JS file to GET the information you want. Then the server responses data based on the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As for the user auth this can reduce the effort

> {% if user.is_authenticated %}

then add script you need

regards